# Windows 8 upgrade to Windows 8 Pro

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

My customer purchased Windows 8 and only Windows 8 Pro has the capability to join to the domain.

Windows 7 had an upgrade key which you can purchase at any store and you can upgrade Windows 7 Home to Pro.

I couldn't find anywhere if it's possible to upgrade a machine with Windows 8 to Windows 8 Pro.

I would like to know if there is any place you can purchase a key to upgrade it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "official" answer is to buy the "Windows Pro Pack Upgrade", which includes Media Center.

This is available in many places, including Amazon, etc.

[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Windows-Pro-Pack-Upgrade/dp/B0093H8W4W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0093H8W4W)

Unfortunately, this is currently retailing for $66.99, or about $20 more than the "Windows 8 Pro Upgrade" that is designed for upgrading XP/Vista/7, and which comes with the ability to obtain a 'Free' license key for the Media Center upgrade.

I would expect that this (Windows 8 Pro Upgrade) could be used to upgrade "Windows 8", but have not tested this.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont grab the Windows 7 to Windows 8 Pro upgrade for $19, have a look here - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwgZIG_FJCs&feature=player_embedded

Comment: or if you still want to go from Windows 8 to PRO upgrade go to - http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbpage.Windows_8_Pro_Pack and get it for only $69.99 !!!!

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!!!  It is called "Windows 8 Pro Pack", thank you Sir!

Comment: @Miroco if this solves your issue, pls. pick it as an answer.